# How to check if an object is either on the keys or in the values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to understand what is the simplest way to check if an object is in either the keys of a dictionary or in the values of a dictionary. I've tried using `.items()` but with no results.

Now I am using this solution but I wonder if there is a better solution:

```
zdict = { 'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
print(list(zdict.values()) + list(zdict.keys()))
'b' in list(zdict.values()) + list(zdict.keys())
```

Comment: `if whatever in zdict or whatever in zdict.values()`???

Answer (score 4):

Stop unecessarily making `list` objects out of the views returned by `.keys` and `.values`. To check if an object is a dictionary key, you simply use `some_object in some_dict`, to check if it is in the values, you use `some_object in some_dict.values()`, so combining both:

```
some_object in some_dict or some_obect in some_dict.values()
```

This is fundamentally going to be a linear operation altogether, but checking if it is in the keys is constant-time, it's a hash-lookup, so you should check that first to take advantage of short-circuiting behavior. Note, if you make a `list` out of the keys then you *force* a linear search.

Comment: yes you are right I've did the list because  I needed for later used. I should have written the question differently

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is simpler but maybe:

```py
any('b'==k or 'b'==v for k,v in zdict.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"b" in sum(zdict.items(), ())
```

We turn the "tuples of list" into a tuple of all keys and values together, making use of the `sum` where we supply an empty tuple for its initial value.

**Edit**: A commenter said above is a quadratic operation. A linear version might be:

```
from itertools import chain
"b" in chain(*zdict.items())
```

Linearity is thanks to the lazy evaluation of `chain`.

Comment: this makes the entire algorithm quadratic time. **never** use `sum` to flatten a sequence. also, this doesn't take advantage of the constant time checking for keys.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for the warning! I added a linear version, i guess. But it still lacks the O(1) of key looking, of course.

Comment: Note, `chain(*zdict.items())` can be `chain.from_iterable(zdict.items())`, which is slightly more efficient, because `*` unpacking creates a *tuple*

Answer (score 0):

This is not much different than others but quite different syntax:

```
any([ k for k, v in zdict.items() if k=='b' or v=='b'])
```